# How do I use two different types of HTTP Cookie Manager type in a Jmeter Test Plan?

Tags: jmeter

I've a typical Jmeter test plan with a login, some user operations and a logout. I've observed that the login passes only if I use an HTTP cookie manager type as Standard which makes the user operations fail. The user operaitons pass only if I use the HTTP cookie manager type rfc2109 which fails the login. Any idea how I can deal with this situation?

I've tried using two HTTP cookie managers in my test plan but only the last cookie manager takes effect. I've also tried including the appropirate cookie manager within the transaction controllers but that didnt work too.
Please advise.

Jmeter version is 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to use two different types of HTTP Cookie Manager in the same Test Plan.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most probably there is a problem with your application under test state management mechanism  - a functional defect in handling cookies so you can [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the HTTP Cookie Manager by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
   ```

   and upon JMeter restart you will see a lot of extra information regarding what's going in with the cookies in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
2. If you don't care about functional defects in your application you can try disabling checking cookies on JMeter level, if there is a problem with the cookie (domain or path mismatch, invalid expiry date and so on) it might help to work around the issue. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```
3. And last but not the least, you can manually extract the cookies from [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and add them to the request [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header using [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), this is basically what HTTP Cookie Manager does under the hood.